# Can an interval be represented as a set?

Tags: probability

In a problem I was asked to to prove the following of a probabilistic model whose sample space is the real line:
$$P([0,\infty))=\lim_{n\to \infty}P([0,n])$$

The solution used the previously proved result 
$$P(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P(A_n)$$
where $A_n$ is an infinite sequence of events, with $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$.

Then the solution just set $A_n=[0,n]$ and $A=[0,\infty)$.

**My question: Is it valid to compare and use somewhat interchangeably an interval and a set?** Is it just possible in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood the question. An interval is a subset of the set $\Bbb R$, hence, a set.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Sorry for the stupid question. Your answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, intervals are sets, $A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le x \le n\}$ and $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0\}$. You can apply the theorem previously proved.

Comment: An interval _is_ a set: a set of real numbers. The "previously proved result" $$P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n\right) $$ is actually equivalent to the third axiom of probability. I like to think of it as saying that probability is a _set-continuous_ function: a real function $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ if for every sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, \ldots$ that converges to $a$, the sequence $f(x_1), f(x_2),\ldots, f(x_n),\ldots$ converged to $f(a)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I don't think you are right but I am not sure. Please read: ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-i/lecture-1/MIT6_041SCF13_assn01.pdf and the accompanying results ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-i/lecture-1/MIT6_041SCF13_assn01_sol.pdf - Read The last problem and the solution. Are you still right?

Comment: @user50224 Yes, I am still right.

Comment: @DilipSarwate But what is the difference between a continous real function and a set-continous function? Because the probability distribution mentioned in the link is not a continous real function because it is only non-zero at $a$ and $b$. Is this still a set-continous function and how would a set-continous function be defined?

Comment: Much of elementary calculus can be said to be a study of continuous functions: those that enjoy the property that for each and every sequence of numbers $\{x_i\}$ converging to a limit $a$, the sequence $\{f(x_i)\}$  converges to $f(a)$, the value of the function $f$ at $a$, i.e. $f($limit$)$ equals limit$(f)$. The probability measure $P(\cdot)$ maps _sets_ to real numbers. For every sequence of sets $\{A_i\}$ that approach a limit $A$, the sequence $P\{A_i\}$ also approaches a limit, and that limit is $P(A)$. Thus, $P(\cdot)$ is said to be _set-continuous:_  $P($limit$)$ equals limit $(P)$

Comment: @Dilipsarwate But what about the last example of the link? There the probability was not continously distributed but only on $a$ and $b$? Nevertheless it satisfied the axioms of probability. That contradicts set continuity, doesn't it?

Comment: Is $a,a,a,a,\cdots$ a sequence whose limit is $a$, and if so, do we exclude this sequence from consideration when we say "A sequence is said to converge to a limit $a$ if $\ldots$" ? Nothing in that last example contradicts set continuity.

Comment: Okay, I think I found my mistake. 1) What is the definition of a limit of a sequence of sets? 2)Let ${a_n}$ be a decreasing sequence that converges to $a$ and ${b_n}$ an increasing sequence that converges to $b$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} [a_n,b_n]=(a,b)$ (which I assume to be true) or is the following true $\lim_{n\to\infty} [a_n,b_n]=[a,b]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an interval can be regarded as a set of points on the real number line.